# CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, matrix-multiplication, cublas

I am doing so-called "tensor contraction" using the [cublasSgemmStridedBatched](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cublas-strided-batched-matrix-multiply/) API. I have tensor A of shape `60000*20*9` and tensor B of shape `9*32`, both of them are row-major. By definition, `C = A * B` should give me the the result tensor C of shape `60000*20*32`. The code that i write is following:

```cpp
    int batch_count = 60000;
    int M = 20;
    int K = 9;
    int N = 32;

    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);
    float alpha = 1.0;
    float beta = 0.0;
    int strideA = 20 * 9;
    int strideB = 0;
    int strideC = 20 * 32;
    // A(60000 * 20 * 9) * B(9 * 32) = C(60000 * 20 * 32)
    cublasStatus_t ret = cublasSgemmStridedBatched(
                              handle, 
                              CUBLAS_OP_N, //transposed, since in row-major
                              CUBLAS_OP_N, //transposed, since in row-major
                              N,
                              M,
                              K,
                              &alpha,
                              B.data<float>(), //already in GPU 
                              N, // lda, transposed
                              strideB, 
                              A.data<float>(), //already in GPU 
                              K, // ldb, transposed
                              strideA, 
                              &beta, 
                              C.data<float>(),//already in GPU 
                              N, // ldc
                              strideC, 
                              batchCount);
    cublasDestroy(handle);
    if(ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS){
      printf("cublasSgemmStridedBatched failed %d line (%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
    }
```

The above code can't get the work done and keeps showing `cublasSgemmStridedBatched failed 7`, which according to [manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/) represents `CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE` . Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: "Transposed LDA" sounds suspicious. When you read in transposed order, the LDA doesn't change

Comment: You mean "lda" should be m instead of k and "ldb" should be k instead of n? that will lead to this error "On entry to SgemmStridedBatched parameter number 10 had an illegal value"

Comment: Both `lda`  and `ldc` should be `M`. The rest looks okay.

Comment: if i change lda to M , then it gives this error: "* On entry to SgemmStridedBatched parameter number 8 had an illegal value"

Comment: Unless I'm bad at counting, that's the `B` pointer. You sure this refers to a pointer in GPU memory?

Comment: Yes i am sure, but 8. parameter refers to "lda" since the first parameter "handle" doesn't count. Also, this error only happens when i change N to M as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal version that works and tests the result:

```cpp
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
  cublasHandle_t cubl;
  cublasCreate(&cubl);
  int batch_count = 60000;
  int M = 20;
  int K = 9;
  int N = 32;
  float* A, *B, *C;
  cudaMallocManaged(&A, sizeof(float) * batch_count * M * K);
  cudaMallocManaged(&B, sizeof(float) * K * N);
  cudaMallocManaged(&C, sizeof(float) * batch_count * M * N);
  for(int b = 0; b < batch_count; ++b)
    for(int m = 0; m < M; ++m)
      for(int k = 0; k < K; ++k)
    A[((b * M) + m) * K + k] = (float)(b + 1) * (m + 2) * (k + 3) / (M*N*K);
  for(int k = 0; k < K; ++k)
    for(int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
      B[k * N + n] = (float) (k + 1) * (n + 2) / (N*K);
  const float alpha = 1.f, beta = 0.f;
  const int strideA = K * M, strideB = 0, strideC = M * N;
  cublasStatus_t ret = cublasSgemmStridedBatched(
    cubl, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, M, K, &alpha,
    B, N /*lda*/, strideB,
    A, K /*ldb*/, strideA, &beta,
    C, N /*ldc*/, strideC, batch_count);
   if(ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
     std::printf("cublasSgemmStridedBatched failed %d line (%d)\n",
                 ret, __LINE__);
   cudaError_t curet = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   std::printf("Device sync: %d\n", ret);
   Eigen::ArrayXXf reference, error = Eigen::ArrayXXf::Zero(N, M);
   const auto B_map = Eigen::MatrixXf::Map(B, N, K);
   for(int b = 0; b < batch_count; ++b) {
     const auto A_map = Eigen::MatrixXf::Map(A + strideA * b, K, M);
     reference.matrix().noalias() = B_map * A_map;
     const auto C_map = Eigen::ArrayXXf::Map(C + strideC * b, N, M);
     const auto rel_error = (C_map - reference).abs() /
           C_map.abs().max(reference.abs());
     error = error.max(rel_error);
   }
   std::printf("Max relative error %g\n", error.maxCoeff());
}
```

Reports a maximum relative error of 2.5e-7

Comment: why is ```strideA``` equals ```K * N``` intstead of ```M * K```? . I think stride[i] means the address difference between matrix[i] and martix[i+1] in the ```batch_count``` matrices?

Comment: @user9875189 right. The switch between A and B sure messes with one's head

Comment: If I change ```batch_count``` from 6 to 60000, the absolute error turns ```5.48031e+08```

Comment: @user9875189 that's just because 1) the individual values increase significantly increasing the maximum absolute error for the same relative error and 2) the sum of all absolute errors naturally increases with the number of computed values. I've changed to the code to 1) generate smaller nonzero values and 2) report the maximum relative error